# Does WSO2 change my WSDL file?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wso2, esb

i've just installed the WSo2 service bus to make my own Service Oriented Architecture (SOA).

I'm trying to connect a Ignition (MES/SCADA) system, to a webservice on another (embedded)computer.
I've made the service in the management console, when i use the tryit function, i can fill in the form, but when i send the message i get the following error:

*"The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/CalculatorWS.CalculatorWSHttpSoap12Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator."*

When i try to do the same within my Ignition program, i get the following error: unknown url type:"calculatorws"?xsd=http.

I think this has to do with the SOAP message, because i compared the one from my webservice, with the one WSO2 generated. 
WSO2 missgenerates the following line within the WSDL:
schemaLocation="CalculatorWS?xsd=http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?xsd=1"
i think this should be: 
schemaLocation="http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?xsd=1"

is this the right conclusion? if yes, how can i adjust it?

besides this, when i use the SOAP Messagetracer from WSO2, i do get the answer i want back! how is this possible?

I'd like to hear from you,
Thanks in advance,
T Dantuma

Comment: Hi Dantuma, WSO2 didn't changed anything that could broke WSDL generating. So there should be something wrong with the configurations. So could you please let me know the followings? 
- ESB version you are using
- Your synapse configs in source view of the service bus section.

Comment: Hi Charitha, thank you for your reply.
The version of my ESB is: 4.9.0
  
`<proxy name="CalculatorWS" startOnLoad="true" statistics="enable"
        trace="enable" transports="http">
                <wsdl port="CalculatorWSPort"
                    service="CalculatorWSService" uri="http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?wsdl"/>
        <publishWSDL uri="http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?WSDL"/>`

I'm sorry, i can't put the whole file inside this comment (too much characters) so i only show the most important parts of it.

Comment: I found out that this line: `<publishWSDL uri="http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?wsdl"/>` 
causes to create the following line in the WSDL file (that the ESB makes): 
`<xsd:import namespace="http://calculator.me.org/" schemaLocation="CalculatorWS?xsd=http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?xsd=1"/>`

Does someone knows how i can adjust this last line?

Answer (score 0):

According to your configuration, it looks like you are going to implement WSDL-based proxy. Then you no need to give published WSDL URL. Try to remove above line from proxy as you mentioned:

```
 <xsd:import namespace="http://calculator.me.org/" schemaLocation="CalculatorWS?xsd=http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/Calcu‌​latorWSService?xsd=1"/>
```

ESB will be adding **xsd** with relevant namespace

- when you define external namespace for given property
- you adding external namespace for service within your service and ESB cannot identify your component. Then it will be use given namespace to solve confusions.

Try above methods. If you cannot identify exact error, please add whole configuration in your question (Edit and put the configuration).

If you still get the error:

- Please log in to WSDL and check whether it can be accessible

http://169.254.166.123:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?wsdl

- Check your invocation method. Becuase "POST" or "GET" request may need special invocations. (Ex: any parameters required for invocation or correct URL may different with exact method)

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/WSDL+Based+Proxy+Template